# Why does getName() return undefined when I define setName() while working with ExtJS config feature?

Tags: javascript, extjs

See the following HTML + JS + ExtJS code that uses the ExtJS config feature.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Ext-JS config missing setAge() problem</title>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/extjs/6.0.0/ext-all.js"></script>
<script>
Ext.define('Student', {
    config: {
        name: 'anonymous',
        age: 0
    },

    constructor: function (config) {
        this.initConfig(config);
    },

    putName: function (name) {
        this.config.name = name
    }

});

var studentObj = Ext.create('Student', {name: 'Alice', age: 12})
console.log('before putName: methods:  ' + studentObj.getName() + ', ' + studentObj.getAge());
console.log('before putName: internal: ' + studentObj._name + ', ' + studentObj._age);
console.log('before putName: config:   ' + studentObj.config.name + ', ' + studentObj.config.age);
studentObj.putName('Bob');
console.log('after putName:  methods:  ' + studentObj.getName() + ', ' + studentObj.getAge());
console.log('after putName:  internal: ' + studentObj._name + ', ' + studentObj._age);
console.log('after putName:  config:   ' + studentObj.config.name + ', ' + studentObj.config.age);
</script>
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

This provides the expected output.

```
"before putName: methods:  Alice, 12"
"before putName: internal: Alice, 12"
"before putName: config:   Alice, 12"
"after putName:  methods:  Alice, 12"
"after putName:  internal: Alice, 12"
"after putName:  config:   Bob, 12"
```

But if I replace `putName` with `setName` in the above code, then I get
the following output.

```
"before setName: methods:  undefined, 12"
"before setName: internal: undefined, 12"
"before setName: config:   Alice, 12"
"after setName:  methods:  undefined, 12"
"after setName:  internal: undefined, 12"
"after setName:  config:   Bob, 12"
```

Why is the internal `_name` variable set to `undefined` in this case? Why does the `getName()` call return `undefined`?

I know that I am not supposed to define my `setName()` method and
instead define `applyName()` method. But I am trying to understand
what's going on here.

It seems to me that when I define the `setName()` method, it messes up
something about how the internal variables for config that are maintained within ExtJS.

Can you describe exactly why the internal `_name` variable is undefined in this case?

Comment: My first guess, it would appear that config.name and the variable used in setName are two different variables. Your putName just changes the config.name variable and not the variable used by setName. Thus, it's never defined, and thus it's undefined when you getName.

Comment: @KФ In the first case, where `putName` changes the `config.name` variable, the variable used by `setName`, i.e. `this._name` is *defined* to `Alice` if you see the outputs I have included in my question. It's only in the case of `setName` that this value is `undefined`.

Comment: The short answer is: "Don't mess with `this.config`", or set the backing properties yourself. You should be sticking to the API, by using appliers, updaters or overriding the setter and calling the parent.

Answer (score 1):

The getter and setter implementation which is automatically generated for `config` members are actually inherited from a parent class - if you override methods that aren't marked as template functions in the API, then you need to call the "super" method if you wish to preserve the original behaviour - you can achieve this by using `callParent`, for example:

```js
Ext.define('MyClass', {

    config: {
        foo: 'bar'
    },

    constructor: function(config){
        this.initConfig(config);
    },

    setFoo: function(value){
        // custom setter code
        this.callParent(arguments);
    }
});
```

Note that if you are choosing to manipulate individual parameters before hand, `callParent` always expects an array - else you can simply pass the function `arguments` as-is.  That said, usually you don't need to override the setter and the documentation makes a point of stating that for reasons of optimization, you shouldn't call any code that would trigger a layout.

An alternative option is to hook onto the `update` template method.  Like getters and setters, each `config` member also gets an *"update"* prefixed method too which by default points to `Ext.emptyFn`.  This method is called after a value has been set and doesn't interfere with the super class, e.g.

```js
Ext.define('MyClass', {

    config: {
        foo: 'bar'
    },

    // ...

    updateFoo: function(value){
        // do something
    }
});
```

[**» Fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/u60xqfL0/)

Answer (score 0):

The default implementation of the getter and setter method uses a property `_<name>` to store the values, that is why it is not working.

If you want to override the `setName` then you need to set `this._name` like

```
Ext.define('Student', {
  config: {
    name: 'anonymous',
    age: 0
  },

  constructor: function(config) {
    this.initConfig(config);
  },

  setName: function(name) {
    this._name = name
  }

});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/3k7bheap/1/)

---

But if a more appropriate way to do this, if you just want to do some custom operation when the property value is set is to use the `apply<property>` method like

```
Ext.define('Student', {
  config: {
    name: 'anonymous',
    age: 0
  },

  constructor: function(config) {
    this.initConfig(config);
  },

  applyName: function(name) {
    return 'some: ' + name
  }

});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/3k7bheap/2/)

Comment: I do understand this like I already mentioned in the question. My question is about why `getName()` returns undefined when we explicitly define `setName()`?

Comment: @LoneLearner because the `setName` is updating `this.config.name` where as it should have updated `this._name` because the default `getName` read that property

Comment: In the first example the `putName` is updating `this.config.name` too. But why in that case `this._name` is properly set to a string? I believe the correct answer would be along the lines of the ExtJS provided `initConfig` method relying on the the ExtJS provided `setName` method to set the internal variables. Since I have replaced the `setName` function with my function, the constructor is unable to set `this._name` anymore.